# Trouble with indexing a string in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am trying to check the first character in each line from a separate data file. This is the loop that I am using, but for some reason I get an error that says string index out of range.

```
for line_no in length:
  line_being_checked = linecache.getline(file_path, line_no)

  print(line_being_checked[0])
```

Comment: What is the variable `length`?

Comment: you probably have an empty line feed.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] -- it makes it so much easier to help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (not very in english), `lenght` is the number of lines you want to check in the files.
You could do something like that:

```
for line in open("file.txt", "r").read().splitlines():
        print(line[0])
```

This way, you'll be sure that the lenght is correct.

For the error, it is possible that you have an empty line, so you could `len(line)` to check if it is the case.